# Need help getting function that returns a window's display image

Tags: java, awtrobot

Is there a function similar to Robot.getScreenCapture() that can return an image from a running program for the display it shows on the monitor? For example I've been trying to take a screenshot of a fullscreen game, but it returns black. I need something with that does the same thing as OBS recorder's gameCapture option, to get an image of a specific window.

edit: To clarify I want to take a screenshot of windows that are not part of this application

Comment: Probably not through Java without resorting to jni/jna solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you knw the coordinates you can get it - what did yu try?

I just did one of a video running and I was able to capture it

Comment: I removed the mention of videos. The main problem I have is that when you're running a game that has a fullscreen option you can't get a screenshot that isn't black.

Comment: it may have to do with hardwar acceleration - on windows you right click ->properties and set it

Comment: also video overlay - if the game is some application that has option for video overlay set/unset